# SQL Server : figure out the tables behind a report, daily email? (I have the to db)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have access to the database in SQL Server Management Studio, I can see all the tables.

We have a daily report sent by email - however we want to know what the SQL query behind the report is, as we cannot get hold of the developers.

Hence I found out the foreign keys and which primary keys they are related to.. but half way through I've come across columns and there doesn't seem to be a key associated with them.

I do not have the time to go through 150+ tables.

How can I find out which table the value has come from without a key?, should there always be a key? Can I search through the entire database, all of the tables for a value in that column so I may find the offending tables - wherever they are?

Help - it's like reverse engineering and taking too long... please

Answer (score 3):

On a Microsoft SQL Server you can use SQL Server Profiler to log all DB queries. If you know the time of the day the report is populated, run the trace at that time, and you'll be able to see the exact SQL statements used for it.

See https://youtu.be/IaxG6jbNuj8

Answer (score 0):

If the report is generated from a stored procedure, then finding the stored procedure would give you all of that info.

This might help you find the stored procedure:

```
select * 
from sysobjects so
inner join  syscomments sc on so.id = sc.id
where sc.text like '%columnname%'
and xtype = 'P'
```

Just put in some search strings (maybe the column outputs) between the % signs.